# How to copy files using regex with grunt.js?

Tags: regex, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I want to copy all js into one folder which belongs to angular Like angular, angular-cookies, angular-resource and angular-route etc.

I was trying to add regex for cwd but it fails to copy.

```
Folder Structure:
app(route folder)
->angular
->angular-cookies
->angular-resource
->angular-route

copy: {
        main: {
        files: [
        {expand: true, cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/angular*', src: ['*.js'], dest:'angular'},
        ]
        }
    }
```